# Connect Oracle through Java program

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, connector

I am trying to connect to Oracle 11g through Java program.Below is my code:-

```
    String dbUrl = "jdbc:oracle://localhost:1521/orcl"; 


    //Database Username     
    String username = "abc";    

    //Database Password     
    String password = "abc";                

    //Query to Execute      
    String query = "select *  from jobs;";

    //Load mysql jdbc driver        
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");       

    //Create Connection to DB       
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl,username,password);

    //Create Statement Object       
   Statement stmt = con.createStatement();                  

        // Execute the SQL Query. Store results in ResultSet        
    ResultSet rs= stmt.executeQuery(query);
```

However i am getting an error message as-
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Invalid Oracle URL specified
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:448)

Please note:I did attach the ojdbc6.jar.

Can you please let me know if i am missing anything?

Comment: Are you, in fact, running Oracle on your local computer? Are you sure?

Answer (score 1):

I believe if You use a old version of driver Oracle JDBC try to change the url connection

Use if this

jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1522/orcl

Comment: I don't get why port 1522 instead of 1521, but you have my upvote because this is right.